# Live "gunshot" sound- cant use blanks- ideas?

Tags: sound-effects, sound-design, live-sound, gunshot

I'm doing the sound design for an adaptation of a Sherlock Homes novella this summer. The venue is outdoors, a raised stage in a field. The play has a number of gunshots, and Production has some reservations about the idea of firing blanks with unsuspecting people possibly walking by. There's always the option of pre-recorded shots, but we'd also like to pursue a live solution.

Have any of you guys had success with something similar?

Comment: Please alert neighbors and businesses nearby that this will be happening. Police have been called in for far less. :-)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ivsnd.com/2010/06/creating-a-machine-gun-sound-from-everyday-objects/

+

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vvadh6YM-RQ

:)

Answer (score 0):

Is the problem that pre-recorded gunshots will sound too canned? Or is it that it will be too hard to synchronize them with the action going on onstage?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest bursting an inflated balloon, as long as the audience don't see you doing it, it can be surprisingly effective.  The larger the balloon the bigger the gun shot.